# NetSuite: Retrieve a value from a popup/subrecord

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suiteql

Thanks for clicking in.

On the **Customer record** within the **Address subtab** I have a sublist with addresses.
On each line there's a **button for edit**. (See first picture)

Clicking edit will bring up a popup window with some fields that can not be seen in Field Explorer. It is one of these fields I would really like to retrieve the value from. (See second picture)

See the third picture to see how the record of the field I want to retrieve looks.

I've tried to both `load the customer record` and to use `lookupFields`. But the field I want can't be accessed through just the customer record. Looking at the field record it says that it is for record of type **Address**. But it says it's a subrecord in record browser, and I don't really know how to access it.

Do I need to create a search in order to get to it? Or is a better way to use SuiteQL?

I'm still a bit new to NetSuite and haven't really done anything with SuiteQL yet.
So any help and guidance is very much appreciated.

**Address Sublist**
[image: Address Sublist]

**Popup**

[image: Popup]

**Field**
[image: Field]

Answer (score 1):

There are different options.

1. When you loaded the customer record, you should load the address sublistrecord to access that value.

```js
define(['N/record'], function(record) {

  var myRecord = record.load({
    type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
    id: INTERNALID_OF_YOUR_CUSTOMER
  })

  for (var line = 0; line < myRecord.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'addressbook' }); line++) {
    var address = myRecord.getSublistSubrecord({ sublistId: 'addressbook', line: line, fieldId: 'addressbookaddress' })
    var accountNo = address.getValue({ fieldId: FIELDID_OF_YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD })
  }

})
```

2. Use the N/search module

```js
define(['N/search'], function(search) {
  
  var mySearch = search.create({
    type: search.Type.CUSTOMER,
    columns: [
      'internalid',
      'entityid',
      'companyname',
      { join: 'Address', name: 'city' },
      { join: 'Address', name: FIELDID_OF_YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD },
    ],
    filters: [ 'internalid', search.Operator.IS, INTERNALID_OF_YOUR_CUSTOMER ]
  })
  
  mySearch.run().each(function(result) {
    ...DO SOMETHING
    return true;
  })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the **subrecord** for getting the values of address.You can use API **recordObj.getCurrentSublistSubrecord**.
Here is the code how i have used to get the values:-

**1-** **First load the customer record in script.**

```
var customerObj = record.load({
             type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
             id: customerRecordId,
             isDynamic:true
         });
 var addressSubrecord = customerObj.getCurrentSublistSubrecord({
         sublistId: 'addressbook',
         fieldId: 'addressbookaddress'
         });
        addressSubrecord.getValue({
             fieldId: 'addr1',
             value: linedata1.address1
         });

         addressSubrecord.getText({
             fieldId: 'country'
         });
         
         addressSubrecord.getValue({
             fieldId: 'addr2'
         });
         addressSubrecord.getValue({
             fieldId: 'zip'
         });
```

**2-Put inside **for loop** if it is according to line using API**  and add line as well.

```
var numLines = objRecord.getLineCount({
    sublistId: 'addressbook'
});
```

You can get all the data using their field id.